# Create Android like grid view in sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2, android-gridview

I am trying to Create Android like grid view in sencha touch 2. The grid view should have 9 buttons with  3 rows and 3 columns. I am very new to sencha,I have been googling but not able to get the solution. Please guide me to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you have two options:

1. A container with layout `vbox` that contains three child items with `hbox` layout
2. A container with layout `hbox` that contains three child items with `vbox` layout

More informations about layout [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/guide/layouts)

I will take the first option since it's an example from Kitchen Sink [demo](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/kitchensink/#demo/buttons):

```
layout: {
    type : 'vbox',
    pack : 'center',
    align: 'stretch'
},

defaults: {
    xtype: 'container',
    flex : 1,
    layout: {
        type : 'hbox',
        align: 'middle'
    },
    defaults: {
        xtype : 'button',
        margin: 15
    }
},

items: [
    {
        items: [
            {text: 'Normal'},
            {ui: 'round', text: 'Round'},
            {ui: 'small', text: 'Small'}
        ]
    },

    {
        items: [
            {ui: 'decline', text: 'Decline'},
            {ui: 'decline-round', text: 'Round'},
            {ui: 'decline-small', text: 'Small'}
        ]
    },
    {
        items: Ext.os.deviceType.toLowerCase() == "phone" ? [
            {ui: 'confirm', text: 'Confirm'},
            {ui: 'confirm-round', text: 'Round'},
            {ui: 'confirm-small', text: 'Small'}
        ] : [
            {ui: 'confirm', text: 'Confirm'},
            {ui: 'confirm-round', text: 'Round'},
            {ui: 'confirm-small', text: 'Small'}
        ]
    }
]
```

Demo: http://www.senchafiddle.com/#XFHkg#sZTqH